# Clarification in a proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am trying to follow the [proof](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/rint.pdf) that the integral of Thomae's function is $0$ over $[0,1]$. The line where the upper bound is $M_i$ is $1$ whenever  $x$ $\notin B_i$ unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The author is being a little loose with notation. What they really mean is $M_i\le 1$, so we may as well consider the worst case in which $M_i=1$ for every $i\not\in B_i$. In short, if we wanted we could improve the bound for various intervals, but we don't need to - if we carry on the computation, we already have enough information to prove the claim.